# Simulate Data for Power of Random Intercepts Model

Tags: mixed-model, simulation, random-effects-model, random-generation

I am interested in calculating the power of a cluster randomized clinical trial of a binary intervention ($T$=1 for treated and $T$=0 for control). I have a pretty set number of candidate clusters from which to sample. I want to understand how many total clusters need to be be involved and the minimum number of clusters that can be in the control.

I will have a population of roughly $K$ groups, each with approximately $n_{k}$ members and I have estimates for their outcome variable in terms of a mean and std for each group ($\mu_{k}$ and $\sigma_{k}$ respectively). From this I think I can simulate the level 1 data (customers) in each group and randomize the groups into treatment and control.

What I am unsure about is how to increase the means for the treated group. Say I hypothesize that on average the mean outcome will increase \$5 for the treated group. I wouldn't increase each mean by \$5 for each group would I?

Are their better ways to accomplish this?